# Binding Command to Event with <i: Interaction.Triggers> Not Working

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to call a method with a button click.

I'm using Visual Studio Community 2015. I installed [Expression Blend](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Expression.Blend.Sdk/) with NuGet Package Manger to get Windows.Interactivity.

My XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="TestApplication.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity" 
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestApplication"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Button Content="Button">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding MessageBoxTest}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

My code behind:

```
namespace TestApplication
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = this;
        }

        public void MessageBoxTest()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Test Successful");
        }
    }
}
```

When I click the button, nothing happens.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot bind method. You should bind property so do it like:

```
private string _messageBoxTest;

    public string MessageBoxTest
    {
       get{ return _messageBoxTest;}
       set{ _messageBoxTest = value;
           RaisePropertyChange(MessageBoxTest);
          }

    }
```

Also You have to implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

You dont have to use InteractionTrigger just simply:

```
  <Button Content="Button"
Command="{Binding MessageBoxTest}">
    </Button>
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize Binding was limited only to properties.

Answer (score 0):

Old question but someone can have the same problem.

If you want to perform some action (`MessageBoxTest here`) after some event (`Click event here`), you should do it with a command.

I usually use the `DelegateCommand` from `Prism library` (I don't like the `C# routed command`).

The usage is like this:

```
public DelegateCommand NameOfCommand = new DelegateCommand(() => MessageBoxTest());
```